# C#- Finding a column index in a dynamic database table in dataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, database, indexing, datagridview

I have a datagridview on my form. And in that datagridview there is a different tables shown from SQL database. Now what i would like to do is somehow find an index of a specific column in table and add a button in every row of that column.

The problem is that the tables in datagridview change, depending on what table do i choose from a combobox on my form.

Maybe if there would be an if statement like this: if some table is shown from combobox, search for specific column in that table and add a button to every row in that column.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Since i haven't found a solution to my problem, im trying to do a workaround. Im trying to make a loop, so when the value in combobox equals "Name" it show a new "datagridview2" table with buttons next to the "Name table in datagridview. And when you select different table then "Name" table, a table "datagridview2" disappears. When the table "Name" is selected in combobox, new datagridview with table "Name" is shown next to it, and it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGrId.png

And the code behind it is:

```
    string selected2 = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        if (selected2 == "Name")
        {
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("Name");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
        }
        else if (selected2 != "Name")
        {
            dataGridView2.Visible = false;

        }
```

The problem is that this if statement doesnt work properly. The datagridview2 with table only shows if the table Name is selected first of from the combobox. And then if i choose some other table from combobox it doesn show up again when table Name is chosen. So there could be some problem with my loop, that i dont know of.

Comment: The problem you describe can be attributed to the fact that you are never making the grid “visible” again. Example: The first time the combo box text is NOT “Name”, will make `dataGridView2` invisible. Switching the combo box text to “Name” will enter the first part of the ‘if’ statement and obligingly add the column and set the grids data source. Unfortunately, the grid is still invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's like this. I have a dgv and cmb which change the content of my dgv (show different structure and data based on the table fetched). If so a think that you'll creating dinamically your dgv and you could add also a button column dinamically in which you can fore example set  runtime in text propert the content of a column varchar.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Well i have a code that gets tables from database:

 string selected = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GECKO-PM\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gecko;Integrated Security=True");
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT* FROM dbo."+selected,con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;